# Can't find GATT service

Tags: uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

In my UWP app, I want to read the device name of other BLE devices. So I am trying to read [this](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.characteristic.gap.device_name.xml) characteristic from the devices. I can find the device's advertising UUID and bluetooth address, but I can not find the default GATT services from it. Here is my code to get the service:

```
if (ulong.TryParse(deviceAddress, out ulong address))
{
    BluetoothLEDevice bluetoothLeDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(address);

    var genericAccessId = ConvertFromInteger(0x1800);

    GattDeviceServicesResult result = await bluetoothLeDevice.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(genericAccessId);

    if (result?.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
    {
        var genericAccess = result.Services.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Uuid == genericAccessId);

        // genericAccess is always null
        if (genericAccess != null)
        {
            var deviceNameId = ConvertFromInteger(0x2A00);
            var deviceName = await genericAccess.GetCharacteristicsForUuidAsync(deviceNameId);

            if (deviceName?.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
            {
                var c = deviceName.Characteristics.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Uuid == deviceNameId);

                if (c != null)
                {
                    var v = await c.ReadValueAsync();

                    if (v?.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                    {
                        var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(v.Value);
                        byte[] input = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
                        reader.ReadBytes(input);

                        // Utilize the data as needed
                        string str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(input);
                        Log?.Invoke(str);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public static Guid ConvertFromInteger(int i)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
    BitConverter.GetBytes(i).CopyTo(bytes, 0);
    return new Guid(bytes);
}

Any idea where the problem is?
```

Comment: What does *I can not find* mean? Does an error occur? Or where does the execution skip the rest of the code?

Comment: Most likely the method `ConvertFromInteger` is incorrect. Try `GattDeviceService.ConvertShortIdToUuid` instead, e.g. `GattDeviceService.ConvertShortIdToUuid(0x1800)`.

Comment: It was just that. Although I was suggested to use `BluetoothUuidHelper.FromShortId` instead since `GattDeviceService.ConvertShortIdToUuid` is obsolete. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BLE device, services and characteristics have a 128 bit UUID for identification. For standardized services and characteristics, there is also a 16 bit short version, e.g. 0x1800 for [Generic Access](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.service.generic_access.xml).

In order to convert a 16 bit to a 128 bit UUID, the 16 bit values has to be filled into the following UUID at byte 2 and 3 (in little endian order:

```
0000xxxx-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB
```

So 0x1800 is converted to:

```
00000018-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB
```

Windows has a function that does it for you: [BluetoothUuidHelper.FromShortId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.bluetoothuuidhelper.fromshortid)

```
var uuid = BluetoothUuidHelper.FromShortId(0x1800);
```

In previous Windows version, you would use [GattDeviceService.ConvertShortIdToUuid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.bluetooth.genericattributeprofile.gattdeviceservice.convertshortidtouuid) instead.

So replace your function `ConvertFromInteger` with the above one. Your function fills in all 0s instead of the above UUID value.